# Omnet simulation stuck at #Run 0 : Initializing

Tags: omnet++

I am using veins, sumo and omnetpp for a traffic simulation . The ide was working good for weeks then all of a sudden the simulation couldnt be initialized and stuck at (My console window)

```
Starting...

$ cd /home/gopal/Downloads/omnetpp-4.6/samples/tictoc
$ tictoc -r 0 omnetpp.ini

OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2014 Andras Varga, OpenSim Ltd.
Version: 4.6, build: 141202-f785492, edition: Academic Public License -- NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE
See the license for distribution terms and warranty disclaimer
Setting up Tkenv...
Loading NED files from .: 17

Loading images from /home/gopal/Downloads/omnetpp-4.6/images: *: 0  maps/*: 9  old/*: 111  abstract/*: 90  block/*: 320  device/*: 195  background/*: 4  misc/*: 70  msg/*: 55  logo/*: 1  status/*: 28  

Plugin path: ./plugins
```

Is this a plugin problem?

To be precise the Tkenv GUI is starting in the toolbar but the window isn't open.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Comment: Having the same problem here; everything was working fine (in Eclipse standards at least) until today. Using version 5.0. I'm starting to hate this environment more and more

Answer (score 3):

No this seems to be unrelated to plugins. BTW, OMNeT++ just printed out that the plugin path is ./plugin. It does not mean it did anything plugin related.

The best way to tackle this issue is to run the simulation in debugger and set breakpoints in different points in your code. I would most likely set some breakpoints in the `initilaization()` functions to see where it spends the time.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem happened to me today. I tried reinstalling (re-downloading and rerunning the scripts needed to install Omnet++ in Windows) and only when I started IDE from the console, I could run my simulations. If I start IDE from the .exe file, I get the same stuck state you described.

I wanted to write this as a comment, but I can't apparently so I'll put it here. It may help you to continue with your project.

Cheers.